# angular 4 get json from php

Tags: php, json, angular

I am trying to get the json of a php execute with angular 4 to populate a table.
Right now I have this to get the data of a json file:

```
export class CountryService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getCountries() {
    return this.http.get('http://cube-developing.de/connect.php')
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => <any[]> res.json().data)
      .then(data => { return data; });
  }
}
```

PHP Part:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("LOGIN DATA")

$result = $conn->query("SELECT _title, _description_short, _displayprice FROM datafeed23");

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}


   $outp .= '{"Produktitel":'  . $rs[_title] . ',';
   $outp .= '"Kurzbeschreibung":'   . $rs[_description_short] . ',';
   $outp .= '"Preis":'. $rs[_displayprice]  . '}'; 
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

Is there a way to get a json from a php Response?

Comment: Yes it's possible. This is like brooooad, if I understood your question correctly. Shortest answer possible: Set up a PHP backend and make http-requests to it :D

Comment: thats what i want :D
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class ProdukteService {
    
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getProdukte() {
        return this.http.get('http://cube-developing.de/connect.php')
                   .toPromise()
                   .then(res => <any[]> res.json().records)
                   .then(records => { return records; });
    }
    }
But thats not working... what do i have to Change to get this working?

Comment: So you have the backend set up? Good. Then just append the complete url, probably `http://cube-developing.de/connect.php` If you don't append `http` in the beginning, Angular will automatically search the url from your localhost (assuming you are running it locally) which it will of course not find such a path.

Comment: the http thing is there :D but stackoverflow changed it

Comment: Yeah, okay :) But open url and you'll see it's not valid JSON so it will never work. You need to get valid JSON from the backend to be able to get the response.

Comment: php part is in answere now :) i guess smth is wrong with that, but i suck at php to be honest... do you find my mistakes ?

Comment: in json you must some characters escape. to please use `json_encode` to translate an array to a json string

Comment: i did, my json is valid now, still not working :/

Comment: escape your keys like `$rs['_description_short']`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have properly configured proxy in your angular project?

Please, look at this tutorial:
https://dzone.com/articles/configure-a-proxy-for-your-api-calls-with-angular

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly and you want to get json instead of javascript object you only have to remove this line `.then(res => <any[]> res.json().data)`.